# Show that if $T(n) \in O(n)$ , then $T(n) \notin \Theta (n^2)$

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

The proposition I would like to prove:

> **Proposition**. If $T(n) \in O(n)$ , then $T(n) \notin \Theta (n^2)$

Since different sources seem to be using slightly different definitions (although I guess all of them are equivalent) , firstly I will list all the relevant definitions:

> If $f,g$ are functions from positive integers to non-negative real numbers, then $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ if and only if for some real $M > 0$ and some natural number $N ≥ 1$ and for all $n ≥ N$, we have $f(n) ≤ Mg(n)$. Also, $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ if and only if for some real $M > 0$ and some natural number $N ≥ 1$ and for all $n ≥ N$, we have $f(n) ≥ Mg(n)$. Finally, $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$ if and only if $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$.

**My attempt**:

For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $T(n) \in \Theta (n^2)$ and $T(n) \in O(n)$. Since $T(n) \in \Theta (n^2)$, it follows that $T(n) \in \Omega (n^2)$, and thus for some real $c > 0$ and for some natural $N ≥  1$,

$$\tag 1cn^2 ≤T(n), \forall n ≥ N$$

Also, since $T(n) \in O(n)$, for some real $k > 0$ and for some natural $M ≥ 1$, we have

$$\tag 2 T(m) ≤ km, \forall m ≥ M$$

Combining results $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude that

$$cn^2 ≤ T(n) ≤ kn, \forall n ≥ \max(N,M)$$

Since $\max(N,M)≥ 1$, it follows that $cn^2 > 0$, and thus we can divide all sides by $cn^2$ to obtain

$$1 ≤ \frac{k}{cn}, \forall n ≥ \max(N,M)$$

Since the sequence $(\frac{k}{cn})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent, we can take limits of both sides to get

$$1 ≤ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{cn} = 0$$

contradiction. $\Box$

---

1. **Is the proof correct?**
2. Are there any shorter alternatives?

Comment: It is correct and there is no better way

Comment: It is indeed correct, but the following might be a bit simpler after you've shown that all $n\geq\max(N,M)$ satisfy $cn^2\le kn$. That last inequality implies $n\le k/c$, and so there would be no natural numbers $n>\max(N,M,k/c)$, which is a contradiction. This may not be shorter than your ending for the proof, but it avoids needing to mention limits.